# Flash actionscript 2.0 - Keys isDown and isToggled alternative

Tags: flash, actionscript

I want some code to only activate once when a key is pressed.

Like in some C-style libraries like SDL where a 'Key-Down' event is generated and then a 'Key-Up' event is generated when you lift the key.

Can something similar be done like this in actionscript 2.0 instead of just a 'isDown' or 'isToggled'.

The closest of ive got to something like this is using a Boolean variable like this

```
var done:Boolean = false
if ( Key.isDown ( Key.SPACE ) && done == false )
{
//code here
done = true;
}
```

The '//Code here' would only run once when the key is pressed which is what i want, but i do not want to create a single variable for each key that i want to check, just seems "ineffecient" if you know what i mean.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a static event listener to the Key object. But still, the key down event will continue to fire at intervals as long as the user holds the key down. You can detect this with a boolean, as you said. Or a map of booleans if you want it a little bit more generic solution. This map tells you which keys are currently down, so you can tell whether the key down event corresponds to the user actually pressing the key or just holding it.

```
var listener:Object = {};
var downMap:Array = [];
listener.onKeyDown = function():Void {
    if(!downMap[Key.getCode()]) {
        trace("first key down:" + Key.getCode());
        downMap[Key.getCode()] = true;
    }
    trace("down:" + Key.getCode());

};
listener.onKeyUp = function():Void {
    trace("up:" + Key.getCode());
    downMap[Key.getCode()] = false;
};
Key.addListener(listener);
```